# Sharing visual studio C# project with native dependencies on the file system

Tags: visual-studio, dll, msbuild, clickonce, projects-and-solutions

I have a shared C# project that uses assemblies which rely on native dlls in the current directory.  This project is used by developers and a build server which uses msbuild to build and deploy the project with clickonce.  There are environmental variables on these machines that specify these native library paths.  I tried to find a way to add the dll to the project and set copy local to true, but there doesn't seem to be a way to add a file link using an environment variable.

Is it even possible to use environment variables in the visual studio IDE?  If not, what is the correct/normal way to handle this?  The dlls need to be found and copied to the output when developers are building and debugging the project from source control, and they need to be added to the click once Application Files when the build server does an msbuild publish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The msbuild project can use environment variables, so you could add a "post build"
task that uses the environment to and start devenv with "devenv /useenv".

For example:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
 <Copy SourceFiles="$(DatabaseSourcePath)\NORTHWND.MDF" 
       DestinationFolder="$(TargetAppDataPath)" />
</Target>
```